# Filling out documents with DocuSign embeded

Tags: docusignapi

We would like to redirect a user from our portal to sign documents. But one of the documents, a skills checklist, also needs to be completed and signed. Is it possible for the user to go through the document and complete form fields within DocuSign ? i.e., the same way a user might fill out an editable PDF. These are mostly check boxes and the forms can vary in length from 30 check boxes to several hundred.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily do this with the DocuSign REST API.  DocuSign helps you manage your entire document workflow through Stick-eTabs:

http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs.

You can add checkboxes, text fields, dates, etc. to your documents and templates and you can use the REST API to programmatically add them when needed, especially when you have a lot like the several hundred you have mentioned.  To add Stick-eTabs (such as Check Boxes) through the API all you have to do is add them in your JSON or XML formatted request bodies.  Generically, it would be a list for each different tab type you want to add, such as:

```
"tabs": {
  "signHereTabs": [{
  }],
  "checkboxTabs": [{
  }],
  "dateSignedTabs": [{
  }],
  ...
}
```

However please note that there are slightly different properties for the different types of tabs.  See this page from the REST API guide that has more info for each tab type:

http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tab%20Parameters.htm

Comment: So, i created a template in DocuSign with a checklist. I then used the drag-and-drop Stick-eTabs to place the check boxes on the page. However, if I do not include an email address in the Roles section of the template, then when the user clicks the embedded link, they are able to access the template but it is in free-form signing mode.

Comment: So, i created a template in DocuSign with a checklist. I then used the drag-and-drop Stick-eTabs to place the check boxes on the page. However, when the user clicks the embedded link, the document is in free-form signing mode and the stick-eTabs do not show up. It seems that it will only work correctly if i add roles manually through the dashboard. I am passing roles through the API because the signers and the recipients are dynamic. To use the drag-and-drop stick-eTabs do I need to enter the roles manually or can i pass them dynamically?

Comment: Yes you will need to save a role name manually with your templates in the console but you don't need to give it an email or username at that point (even if you do you can override their values through the api).  Then when you make your signature request from template API call you match your recipients to the template roles through the **roleName** property.  If you are ending up in a free form signing experience then that means they are not being matched to a role currently.